# $\mathit{NP}$-hard statements which are $\mathit{NP}$-complete under the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, computational-complexity, riemann-hypothesis, np

$\newcommand\NP{\mathit{NP}}\newcommand\SAT{\mathit{SAT}}\newcommand\CH{\mathit{CH}}\newcommand\PSPACE{\mathit{PSPACE}}$Are there $\NP$-hard problems which are $\NP$-complete under the Riemann Hypothesis corresponding to the following cases?

1. Superpolynomial certificate length becomes polynomial sized.
2. Randomized polynomial time reduction to $\SAT$ becomes deterministic polynomial time reduction.
3. Reduction to $\SAT$ becomes polynomial deterministic time from superpolynomial deterministic time.
4. Certificate becomes polynomial time verifiable.
5. An infinitely often reduction always holds.
6. The problem was originally in $\CH$ (counting hierarchy) or below and strictly in $\PSPACE$.

I think 2. and 6. **are impossible unless RH is false** and so might be difficult to identify while 1., 3. and 4. might be similar.

**Bounty is for 2. or 6.**

**I would be happy to award for 2. and 6. if there is a reduction for these under the condition of failure of RH and in my opinion such a twisted reduction is allowed but just 2. and 6. are disallowed under correctness of RH.**

It would be amazing if there are reductions to 2. and 6. under both truth and falseness of RH and this I think is unlikely since I think reduction under truth of RH is unlikely.

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0885064X96900199 shows that Nullstellensatz is in a class "just above" NP if GRH is true.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Conjecturally, the class is indeed NP itself, making the problem NP-complete. That is, what Koiran proves is that assuming GRH, solvability of (integer) polynomial systems in $\mathbb C$ is computable in AM. (I’m not sure why he calls it “Nullstellensatz”, as the Nullstellensatz is a theorem, not a computational problem.) There are plausible complexity-theoretic conjectures that imply AM = NP.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I think it answers an analogous version of 1. and 3.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek If the problem was unconditionally below PSPAPCE in Benjamin Steinberg's comment it would answer 6.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example, but you may consider it to be a bit artificial Consider the following language: s is in $L$ if $S=(x,y)$ where $x$ is a 3-SAT instance, $y$ is a satisfying instance for $y$, and also satisfying that if $n$ is the number of true variables in $y$, then the $n$th non-trivial zero of the zeta function has real part equal to $1/2$. But this is a bit artificial. My guess is that you specified your five examples in order to avoid that.

Edit: The following does not work. Possibly it can be fixed, but see Emil's comment below.

But we can modify this is a little bit to cheat and get an example of 1, provided one is willing to use GRH rather than RH; my guess is that a similar construction can be done with RH, but it doesn't immediately jump out at me.  The first detail is that assuming GRH, the smallest positive primitive root $u$,  of a prime $p$ is bounded above by a power of $\log p$. In particular, Shoup showed that $u = O( (\log p)^6)$.

Given positive constants $c_1$, $c_2$, and a function $f(n)$ Let $A_{c_1,c_2, f(n)}$ be the language given by the following: $a$ is in $A$ if $a=(x,y,z,w)$ where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are defined as follows. We have $x$ is a 3-SAT instance and $y$ is a satisfying set of variables for $x$. $z$ is a prime $p$ such that $y< p < (c_1)p^{c_2}$ (where we are thinking of our list $y$ of variable assignments as just a binary number). We have $w$ is a string of 1s where the number of 1s is a primitive root of $p$, and $w$'s length is bounded by $f(p)$.

Now, we can choose a $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that there is always such a prime $p$ when there is a $y$. (Baker, Harman and Pintz showed that one can take $c_2 = 0.525$). So choose such a $c_1$ and $c_2$. Then, note that if we believe GRH, we can always find such a $w$ which is polynomial in the length of $x$, and we can choose $f(n)$ so that $w$'s length is guaranteed to be less than $f(p)$ if GRH is true.

So now our NP-hard question then is just is a given $x$ a valid $x$ for an $(x,y,z,w)$ in $A$? If GRH is true, we can always find a $y$, $z$ and $w$ which is guaranteed to be just polynomial in length when $x$ is true. But without GRH we can only get that this is NP-hard since our $w$ may be too large.

*This is essentially just a padding trick. My guess is that a similar padding trick can be used with just RH as an assumption but I don't immediately see how to do it.  And this is still a pretty artificial problem. I'd be interested to see if someone has a more natural example.*

Comment: I cannot make sense of the example. As far as I can see, the language $\{x:\exists y,z,w\,(x,y,z,w)\in A\}$ is *unconditionally* in NP, because it equals $\{x:\exists y,z,w\,(x,y,z,w)\in A'\}$, where $A'$ is defined just like $A$, except that $w$ is written in binary rather than unary. (Actually, neither $A$ nor $A'$ is computable in polynomial-time, as verifying that something is a primitive root requires factorization of $p-1$. But this is not a problem, as the factorization of $p-1$ can be taken as part of the witness.) On the other hand, it’s not clear to me why is the language NP-hard.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek You are correct. This doesn't work. I think some padding trick should be doable but my attempted answer has multiple problems.